Backup request via API management API failing
I have a LogicApp running once a day to backup API management
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.ApiManagement/service/{service}/backup?api-version=2022-08-01
It's failing (status code 400) with the message "Invalid parameter, this request is not authorised to perform this operations.
These are the things I have setup and checked

The registered app setup in Entra used to get the access token has Azure service management and Azure storage API permissions
The storage account networking is set to 'Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses' There is an entry in resource instances for Microsoft.ApiManagement/service
The managed identity on the LogicApp is enabled
The managed identify on API management is enabled
The storage account IAM setup has an entry for both identities each with Storage Blob Data Contributor which has been inherited by the blob container.
All of these settings were up to date before 6pm last night and the flow ran at 7am this morning, so propogation shouldn't be a problem

Appreciate there might be things I don't need but i've been layering and I feel like I've run out of things!
If anyone can help, that would be greatly appreciated.

are you using system managed identity for backup?

That's a good point (i didn't set the flow up), assuming you mean what's in the request body, the access type is AccessKey, so is does it make a lot of what I've said irrelevant?

are you passing bearer token in request header?

Yes, this has all come about because the storage account was open to all networks so I've locked it down, but it worked when it was open, so it's not an issue with the registered app/permissions/token

I've changed the payload so the accessType is SystemAssignedManageIdentity and added the identoty property with the client ID as the value and that seems to be working now.

In order to pass the client ID, you should be using user assigned managed identity as access type as there is no client id required for system managed identity
